# Mac OS X: how do I change to Qwerty / Dvorak with a terminal command?

Tags: macos, mac, automator, dvorak

I want to use Automator to change to Qwerty before it opens StarCraft2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/157229/application-specific-default-keyboard-layout-in-mac-os-x/185422#185422

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the default keyboard command to change your input method between Qwerty and Dvorak? By default it's <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Naw, I want to use Automator to do it, cause I want to switch to qwerty and open StarCraft all in one shortcut key... I would vote down this answer if I had my stackOverflow reputation.

Comment: @DerNalia wow that's pretty harsh, especially since it's trivial to use Automator to automatically *hit the command-space shortcut*.

Comment: fair enough. didn't know I could do that. thanks for the idea.

Comment: I think a downvote for an answer which merely misunderstands your intentions would be uncalled for...

Comment: yeah, I upvoted =)

Answer (score 5):

Applescript to hit the default shortcut to switch keyboard layouts. *(See the Keyboard Shortcuts tab of your Keyboard preference pane to ensure it's enabled and modify shortcut as necessary.)*

```
tell application "System Events"
   keystroke " " using {command down}
end tell
```

Add the run AppleScript to your automator, and then the Launch Application.